# error install openvpn in ubuntu 12.04 lts

Tags: networking, vpn

```
$ sudo apt-get install openvpn
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree   
Reading state information... Done
openvpn is already the newest version.
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
default-jdk openjdk-6-jdk
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Comment: your system installed openvpn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Openvpn was installed. You can use the auto remove suggestion to clean up files you don't need that were also installed. Also if you can't find an icon for it in your programs list you can always run it down the command line.